# How do I query Entity Framework for a user in aspnet_Users?

Tags: asp.net, linq, entity-framework

I have added the SqlRoleProvider tables aspnet_Users, aspnet_Roles, and aspnet_UsersInRoles to my Entity Framework 1.0 model in VS 2008.

[image: Users and roles]

I've tried the following which intellisense won't even help me with.

```
private void BindFormView(string userName)
{
    using (var context = new MyEntities())
    {
        var users = from u in context.aspnet_Users
                    where  u.UserName = userName
                    select u;

    }
    //...
}
```

My eventual goal is to get all of the roles a given user has. It's all looks right in my model, but I cannot seem to access it effectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dude, **do not** map the membership tables.

Access them via the Membership Provider API:

```
Membership.GetUser("blah");
```

Why shouldn't you map it?

- Because it's presuming SQL (defeats the point of a "model" abstraction in EF)
- Kidding yourself if you can figure out the complex relationships/associations in the database

The Membership API has all the information you require.

To get the roles for a user, use **[RoleProvider.GetRolesForUser](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprovider.getrolesforuser.aspx)**

Comment: The odd thing about this particular application is that I must manage users roles through the UI. Binding a DataGridView to an entity was fairly straigt forward. With the Membership Provider API I had a string array of user names, which was not as nice to work with.

Comment: Look im sure its *possible*, but there are just too many reasons why you shouldn't bother. Can't you just have your UI access a method which does "RoleProvider.GetRolesForUser"?

Comment: I can get the RoleProvider.GetRolesForUser to work, but I cannot get the user. I'm getting the string "AMERICAS\myName" from the entity (working my way back) so it's not a typo in this case.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean. `Membership.GetUser` has several overloads, but will return a `MembershipUser` entity. This is what you should be working with.

Comment: I mean that, even though I am authenticated, Membership.GetUser(userName) returns null, whereas Roles.GetRolesForUser(userName) successfully returns a string array.

Comment: Most likely you are not passing the correct argument to `Membership.GetUser`. It needs to match the username you created the user with `Membership.CreateUser`. Have a look at the membership records (in sql server), look for the "Username" field. That's what you need to pass to `GetUser`. Either that, or you have a problem with your Identity/Authentication. To check that, you should wrap the GetUser call around `if User.Identity.IsAuthenticated == true`. As if that flag is not true, `GetUser` will return null.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the roles are setup as a navigation property from the users.  So, building on your code you should be able to do something like this:

```
private void BindFormView(string userName)
{
    using (var context = new MyEntities())
    {
        //Get the first user matching your query
        var user = (from u in context.aspnet_Users
                    where  u.UserName == userName
                    select u).FirstOrDefault();

        //Using the navigation properties, get the roles associated with this user
        var roles = user.aspnet_Roles().ToList();

    }
    //...
}
```

Comment: Alas no. "Cannot resolve method 'Where(lambda expression)...". Intellisense for the var roles = user yields only a For method. Thanks for your help, but I think I'm going to have to get out of the corner I've painted myself into :)

Comment: Ah, ok.  I noticied a typo in my post...this:  u.UserName = userName should be this:  u.UserName == userName for c#.  Not sure if you already fixed that or not...

Comment: That did fix the query expression. Thanks.